# How do I render a component from one react application into another?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have one react application that contains a navbar component, I want to return a HTML blob with the navbar component when called from another application(Need not be a react app). Basically I want to be able to render the navbar component across multiple applications.

I am new to react, any suggestions will be appreciated !

Thanks!

Comment: You want to render the react component, in a non-react app? If so, you will need to "build" this component(create a separate react-app just for this component), then build it into bundle.js/chunks, and just manually use them in some in some non-react web page.

Comment: The thing is that the navbar is very dynamic and gets populated based on user permission for each application. So how can I build such a component that talks to the application backend to render itself based on permissions.

Comment: You're mixing many things here dude....Try to be more clear about exactly what you want, while pin-pointing the key issue. A dynamic component is totally normal, no matter what front-end platform you use, but it has nothing to do with the backend(unless your entire website is server side rendered, like Wordpress sites)

Comment: A "normal" react application would fetch some data from he backend(like maybe your permissions), and then render the component(s) dynamically, according to that fetched data.